How can I install JRE/Java in pydroid3
Everytime when I run h2o on pydroid3 then it says I need Java/JRE for it to work. ERROR:
Checking whether there is an H2O instance running at http://localhost:54321..... not found.
Attempting to start a local H2O server...
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.11/site-packages/h2o/h2o.py", line 270, in init
h2oconn = H2OConnection.open(url=url, ip=ip, port=port, name=name, https=https,

          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.11/site-packages/h2o/backend/connection.py", line 406, in open
conn._cluster = conn._test_connection(retries, messages=msgs)

                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.11/site-packages/h2o/backend/connection.py", line 713, in _test_connection
raise H2OConnectionError("Could not establish link to the H2O cloud %s after %d retries\n%s"

h2o.exceptions.H2OConnectionError: Could not establish link to the H2O cloud http://localhost:54321 after 5 retries
[22:07.97] H2OConnectionError: Unexpected HTTP error: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=54321): Max retries exceeded with url: /3/Metadata/schemas/CloudV3 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x79554692d0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
[22:08.19] H2OConnectionError: Unexpected HTTP error: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=54321): Max retries exceeded with url: /3/Metadata/schemas/CloudV3 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x795546b1d0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
[22:08.41] H2OConnectionError: Unexpected HTTP error: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=54321): Max retries exceeded with url: /3/Metadata/schemas/CloudV3 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x795546b810>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
[22:08.63] H2OConnectionError: Unexpected HTTP error: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=54321): Max retries exceeded with url: /3/Metadata/schemas/CloudV3 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7955065450>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
[22:08.85] H2OConnectionError: Unexpected HTTP error: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=54321): Max retries exceeded with url: /3/Metadata/schemas/CloudV3 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7955067390>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line 31, in 
start(fakepyfile,mainpyfile)

File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line 30, in start
exec(open(mainpyfile).read(),  __main__.__dict__)

File "", line 19, in 
File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.11/site-packages/h2o/h2o.py", line 287, in init
hs = H2OLocalServer.start(nthreads=nthreads, enable_assertions=enable_assertions, max_mem_size=mmax,

     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.11/site-packages/h2o/backend/server.py", line 139, in start
hs._launch_server(port=port, baseport=baseport, nthreads=int(nthreads), ea=enable_assertions,

File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.11/site-packages/h2o/backend/server.py", line 271, in _launch_server
java = self._find_java()

       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.11/site-packages/h2o/backend/server.py", line 453, in _find_java
raise H2OStartupError("Cannot find Java. Please install the latest JRE from\n"

h2o.exceptions.H2OStartupError: Cannot find Java. Please install the latest JRE from
http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/welcome.html#java-requirements
[Program finished]
I tried nothing, cant find any information to download it.

SDKMAN!

I think there might be two issues:

installing correct version of java,
telling H2O where the java is.

I'm not sure what's the best way to do the (1) but I think I might help with the (2).
Once you install java and if it doesn't work, it's likely due to different than usual file paths. To mitigate this issue you can set JAVA_HOME or H2O_JAVA_HOME environment variables to point to your java installation or you can even start the h2o backend manually and then call h2o.connect() instead of h2o.init().
